# Array in object vba

Tags: vba

I have 2 classes

Class1

```
Private pClass2Arr(10) as Class2

Public Property Get class2Arr() as Class2()
    class2Arr = pClass2Arr
End Property

Public Property Let class2Arr(mClass2Arr() as Class2)
    pClass2Arr = mClass2Arr
End Property
```

Class2

```
Private pStr1 as String
Private pStr2 as String

Public Property Get str1() as String
    str1 = pStr1
End Property

Public Property Let str1(mStr1 as String)
    pStr1 = mStr1
End Property

Public Property Get str2() as String
    str2 = pStr2
End Property

Public Property Let str2(mStr2 as String)
    pStr2 = mStr2
End Property
```

And Id' like to do

```
Dim a as Class1
Set a = New Class1
a.class2Arr(0).str1 = "test"
Debug.Print a.class2Arr(0).str1
```

And I have an error because get property on class2Arr have no arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just declared array, but not initialized it `Private pClass2Arr(10) as Class2`. I've added `Private Sub Class_Initialize()` event in `Class1`:

```
Private pClass2Arr(10) As Class2

Public Property Get class2Arr() As Class2()
    class2Arr = pClass2Arr
End Property

Public Property Let class2Arr(mClass2Arr() As Class2)
    pClass2Arr = mClass2Arr
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Dim i As Byte ' change Byte to Integer if your array contains more than 255 elements
    For i = LBound(pClass2Arr) To UBound(pClass2Arr)
        Set pClass2Arr(i) = New Class2
    Next
End Sub
```

and then you can use it like this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim a As Class1
    Set a = New Class1
    a.class2Arr()(0).str1 = "test"
    Debug.Print a.class2Arr()(0).str1
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I add the constructor but I have the same error

Comment: have you changed `a.class2Arr(0).str1 = "test"` to `a.class2Arr()(0).str1 = "test"` as in my code?

Comment: I didn't notice this, it works, thanks for your help :)